# How to restore Bitbucket Backup using SCM Backup?

Tags: bitbucket, backup, restore

I recently tried to take a backup of my BitBucket repositories using SCM Backup. Here is what I did:

Installed dot net on my MacOS

Installed SCM Backup

I created an App Password for SCM Backup in BitBucket.

I made the following changes in the settings.yml file:

```
# all backups go here
localFolder: 'c:\scm-backup'

# when an error occurs, wait that many seconds before exiting the application
waitSecondsOnError: 5

# uncomment this to send SCM Backup's console output via email
#email:
#  from: from@example.com
#  to: to@example.com
#  server: smtp.example.com
#  port: 0
#  useSsl: false
#  userName: testuser
#  password: not-the-real-password

sources:

  - title:  bitbucket_bkp
    hoster: bitbucket
    type: org
    name: my_username
    authName: my_username
    password: App Password that I created
```

Now when I run -

```
dotnet ScmBackup.dll
```

It gives the output -

```
SCM Backup 1.2.1.552abf5
https://scm-backup.org/
Backing up config files
Getting repositories for source 'bitbucket_bkp' from hoster 'bitbucket'
Trying to find SCMs on this machine...
Backing up source: bitbucket_bkp
Backup finished!
The backups are in this directory: c:\scm-backup
```

How do I restore the repositories from this c:\scm-backup file?

I am clueless about it.

Also as per the documentation [bitbucket-scm-backup](http://docs.scm-backup.org/en/latest/config-bitbucket/) when I give the team name in the name field in the setting field it gives the below error:

```
SCM Backup 1.2.1.552abf5
https://scm-backup.org/
Backing up config files
Getting repositories for source 'bitbucket_bkp' from hoster 'bitbucket'
User my_team_name not found!
Backup failed!
The application will close in 5 seconds!
```

I want to take the backup of all the repositories of my team in BitBucket and restore it ?

What should I do ?

As per Chris suggestion I made the following changes in the settings.yml file -

```
# all backups go here
localFolder: '/Users/rahman/Desktop/'
```

Now when I take the backup I get a folder called *bitbucket_bkp* in my Desktop. But it is empty. How do I restore it?

Also how can I take the backup of the entire team by specifying the team name? It is not working for me.

To take the backup of my team I have made changes to the settings file like this -

```
# all backups go here
localFolder: '/Users/rahman/Desktop/riz_bkp/'

# when an error occurs, wait that many seconds before exiting the application
waitSecondsOnError: 5

# uncomment this to send SCM Backup's console output via email
#email:
#  from: from@example.com
#  to: to@example.com
#  server: smtp.example.com
#  port: 0
#  useSsl: false
#  userName: testuser
#  password: not-the-real-password

sources:

  - title:  bitbucket_bkp
    hoster: bitbucket
    type: org
    name: team_name
```

Now I get the error-

```
SCM Backup 1.2.1.552abf5
https://scm-backup.org/
bitbucket_bkp: AuthName and Password are empty. Without authentication, SCM Backup will backup public repositories only!
Backing up config files
Getting repositories for source 'bitbucket_bkp' from hoster 'bitbucket'
User team_name not found!
Backup failed!
The application will close in 5 seconds!
```

What to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question 1: "How do I restore the repositories from this c:\scm-backup file?"

Glad to hear that SCM Backup works on MacOS, but please note this in the [System Requirements](https://docs.scm-backup.org/en/latest/install/#system-requirements):

> So far, SCM Backup has been written and tested on Windows only. Technically, it should run on Linux and MacOS as well, but this has not been tested yet.

I'm on Windows, and `c:\scm-backup` is a valid folder/directory on Windows, but will probably not work on a Mac.
(`c:` is the system drive on Windows)

I don't have access to a Mac, so I can't test anything...but according to what I just googled, you should use a path like `/Users/your_user/Documents/scm-backup`.

The path should already exist, and the user which is running SCM Backup should have write access to it.
If you can confirm that this works, I'll add it to the docs.

#### Concerning restores:

You probably read [the documentation about restoring](https://docs.scm-backup.org/en/latest/restore/). The technical steps how to do the actual restore are described there, but what's missing right now is the description how the content of the local folder.

I'll add that to the documentation, but here's the short version:

After changing `localFolder` from `c:\scm-backup` to whatever works on MacOS, run SCM Backup and the folder should contain one subfolder per [source defined in the config](https://docs.scm-backup.org/en/latest/config/#sources). So in your case, it should be named `bitbucket_bkp`.

Inside, there's one subfolder for each repository, and inside *that*, there's at least one subfolder `repo` (and maybe another named `wiki`, if that repo has a wiki).

**This `repo` folder contains a full clone of your repository from Bitbucket, and this is the "local repository" that [the documentation about restoring](https://docs.scm-backup.org/en/latest/restore/) refers to.**

---

### Question 2: The backup gives an error when you try to backup a team

Please see [the docs about sources in the configuration](https://docs.scm-backup.org/en/latest/config/#sources):

> Each source must have at least those four properties:
>
> [...]
>
> `type`
>
> Either `user` or `org`, depending if you want to backup an user or a organization.
>
> `name`
>
> The name of the user/organization you want to backup.

So it's either:

```
type: user
name: my_username
```

or:

```
type: org
name: my_team_name
```

In the example config you posted, it's a mixture of both.

Comment: Hi. I made a few changes to the settings.yml file. I specified the local folder as /User/rahman/Desktop. Now I have a folder called bitbucket_bkp after taking the backup but the folder is empty! How do I restore? Also the type:org does not work for me? Can you specify how to use the team backup option?

Comment: If the output still looks like the one posted in your question, then I'm suspecting that your team doesn't have any repositories. Just to be clear: SCM Backup tries to backup the repositories of the team (`https://bitbucket.org/my_team_name/repo_name`), **not the repositories of the users who are members of the team!!**

Comment: Hey @Christian. I have change the settings file again. It just has the type: org and name: team name. Now I get the error - User *team name* not found. What could be the reason ?

Comment: If your team is private, you need to set `authName` and `password` as well. SCM Backup uses the Bitbucket API to get a list of your team's repositories, and that specific error message is shown when the API returns a 404...which probably happens because the API doesn't return anything at all for a private team without autentication.

Comment: Hey @Christian . I was finally able to identify the issue. It is working well now. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Great to hear! So, what was the actual issue? Anything that I could add to the documentation, which would have helped you?

Answer (score 2):

### **SCM-Backup and Docker Desktop on MacOS with Apple Silicon**

```
2023 Update: 
scm-backup: 1.7.0
Docker: Docker Desktop 4.21.1
MacOS: 13.4.1
Apple Silicon: M1 Pro
```

(I used Juris' comment from: https://github.com/christianspecht/scm-backup/issues/49#issuecomment-830032953
and updated the versions)

```
Dockerfile
```

content:

```
FROM alpine:3.18

ARG SCM_FILE=scm-backup-1.7.0.6090ea9.zip
ARG DOTNET_FILE=dotnet-runtime-3.1.14-linux-musl-x64.tar.gz
ARG DOTNET_FILE_SHA512=77856f6183ef7ee561fe8510e89148566972ae21e3915242ae4ac7ef987b1aa78cda09bb06fdae96cd03758975dc5eb0e8652dea79b96db327ac5de2a4d41961

ENV SCM_ROOT=/opt/scm-backup
ENV DOTNET_ROOT=/opt/dotnet
ENV PATH=${PATH}:${DOTNET_ROOT}

WORKDIR ${SCM_ROOT}

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        bash icu-libs krb5-libs \
        libgcc libintl libssl1.1 \
        libstdc++ zlib curl git \
 # Install dotnet runtime
 && curl -fsL -o ${DOTNET_FILE} https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/e7f88aae-a10e-4b49-8ccd-31f2df82cf3f/35fb27716a3b7543ef2889f0e4c19949/${DOTNET_FILE} \
 && echo "${DOTNET_FILE_SHA512}  ${DOTNET_FILE}" > ${DOTNET_FILE}.sha512 \
 && sha512sum -c ${DOTNET_FILE}.sha512 \
 && mkdir -p ${DOTNET_ROOT} \
 && tar zxf ${DOTNET_FILE} -C ${DOTNET_ROOT} \
 # Install scm-backup
 && curl -fsL -o ${SCM_FILE} https://github.com/christianspecht/scm-backup/releases/download/1.7.0/${SCM_FILE} \
 && unzip ${SCM_FILE} \
 && rm -f ${SCM_FILE} ${DOTNET_FILE} ${DOTNET_FILE}.sha512 

COPY settings.yml .

ENTRYPOINT dotnet ScmBackup.dll
```

---

```
settings.yml
```

content:

```
localFolder: '/scm-backup-out'

sources:
  - title: git_backup_from_bitbucket
    hoster: bitbucket
    type: org
    name: team_or_workspace_name_here
    authName: username_here_not_email_address
    password: app_password_here
```

Folder structure:

```
bitbucket-backups (folder)
Dockerfile
settings.yml
```

Usage:

```
docker pull alpine:3.18

docker build --progress plain --platform linux/x86_64 -t scm-backup .

docker run -v ${PWD}:/opt/scm-backup/backup --mount src=`pwd`/bitbucket-backups,target=/scm-backup-out,type=bind scm-backup
```